# Running GWT on tomcat in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, tomcat

I am trying to get a GWT Project running on a Tomcat 7 server in eclipse. I installed Tomcat and i can run other web application out of eclipse on Tomcat without a problem.

Now i generated a gwt maven project for eclipse with the following command and importet it as maven project to eclipse:
"mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin"

I can run this now as Web application (with the google plugin) and i can build a "war" with maven and deploy this with the Tomcat management console on the server. Both is working. But if i choose the option in eclipse "Run on server" and choose tomcat than just the html is loaded but not the application itself. See the screenshot: It doesn't find the "GWTModule.nocache.js".

[image: Application not running]

This file is available in the target folder. What do i have to change to tell tomcat to look in the correct directory?

[image: project layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat is not able to run GWT code in development mode. You can use Tomcat for server side code, but in this case you need to run GWT development mode with `-noserver` option (to prevent built-in Jetty instance from running). See [this article](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s) for more details.

Comment: Is there any specific server for GWT?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the wtp plugin for eclipse. If you do this you can add your project/resource to tomcat when adding a new server. Here are the steps to use if you already have your project imported into eclipse.

Window -> Show View -> Servers

In Servers 
New -> Server -> Choose apache tomcat

Point to the location of your tomcat installation/download 
Next

At this point you should be able to add your gwt-maven project which will add the target/project.war to the tomcat modules.

Save it

Click on the newly added server, then click the modules tab at the bottom kind of hard to see.

This should have your project shown in the list of web modules.

Start your tomcat instance then on your gwt application right click and choose Run As -> Web application. Make sure your configuration settings are correct and when the development server starts it should give you the development url to browse to.

You can configure some aspects of tomcat in the overview tab, I would recommend making sure that "Modules auto reload by default" is checked so that tomcat will watch the filesystem for class changes.

Comment: Hey, I've tried to go Your way, but unfortunately I can't add my gwt maven app to tomcat server resources. My application isn't on availables list. I don't know why. [I've posted question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267093/eclipse-tomcat-resources-available-list-doesnt-contain-gwt-2-7-0-maven-app).
 Can You look at it? Maybe You could help me?